# Should I take home a profit which is a large part of my equity?

Tags: investment-strategies, day-trading, profitability

At my account with my trading platform I have about 10 000 USD in balance and about 17 000 in Equity and an outstanding profit of about 6000 USD. Is it better to sell and take home half the profit now that is clearly is a profit or should I wait for even more gains?

Comment: According to the tags, you're a day trader.  Thus, don't you *frequently* sell?

Comment: @RonJohn I might not be a day trader because I follow longer trends and use strategies to sell larger amounts less frequently than daily. It can be discusses. Nearly all my gains are from the bitcoin rally recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you should cash out depends on your risk tolerance, but that's a general answer for **any** kind of trading, and we can't help you with that.

Note that you'll have to pay capital gains tax on any profit.  Presumably you've held these btc for less than a year (short term gains).  That means the rate will be equivalent to your marginal income tax rate.  If you've held them longer than a year, then that's long-term gains.

https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/101515/comparing-longterm-vs-shortterm-capital-gain-tax-rates.asp

So, if you cash out, remember to sock away a percentage for Uncle Sam!